# Why getFrameAtIndex faster than getFrameAtTime()

Tags: java, android, mediametadataretriever

I'm trying to get all frames (one by one) from a video, right now I'm using this :

```
    int framesCount = videoInformation.getFramesCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < framesCount; i++) {
         Bitmap currentFrame = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtIndex(i);
```

For **5 sec** video, it's take **13 seconds** to extract all frames (159 frames).

Since `getFrameAtIndex(i)` requires API 28, I tried to use `getFrameAtTime()`

```
    long timeS = videoInformation.getDuration() / videoInformation.getFps();
    int framesCount = videoInformation.getFramesCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < framesCount; i++) {
          Bitmap currentFrame = (mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(i*timeS*1000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC));
```

For the same **5 sec** video, it's take almost **48sec** to get all frames.

Answer (score 1):

I cant speak for the native implementations for both, as both of these functions call their respective native functions, however, if you look at the `getFrameAtIndex`, you can see that it:

Has access to the total `framecount` by reading the `metadata`, and retrieves a frame using an `index`, similar to `Arrays`.

```
int frameCount = Integer.parseInt(extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_FRAME_COUNT));
```

`getFrameAtIndex()` calls `getFramesAtIndexInternal()`

```
   private @NonNull List<Bitmap> getFramesAtIndexInternal(
            int frameIndex, int numFrames, @Nullable BitmapParams params) {
        if (!"yes".equals(extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_HAS_VIDEO))) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Does not contain video or image sequences");
        }
        int frameCount = Integer.parseInt(
                extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_FRAME_COUNT));
        if (frameIndex < 0 || numFrames < 1
                || frameIndex >= frameCount
                || frameIndex > frameCount - numFrames) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid frameIndex or numFrames: "
                + frameIndex + ", " + numFrames);
        }
        return _getFrameAtIndex(frameIndex, numFrames, params);
    }
```

while `getFrameAtTime` is not really index based, but rather seeks/searches until it matches a Frame timestamp with the required time you passed, or the closest one:

```
public @Nullable Bitmap getFrameAtTime(long timeUs, @Option int option) {
    if (option < OPTION_PREVIOUS_SYNC ||
        option > OPTION_CLOSEST) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported option: " + option);
    }

    return _getFrameAtTime(timeUs, option, -1 /*dst_width*/, -1 /*dst_height*/, null);
}
```

https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/java/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.java